# Pegar Nome da Taxonomia de acordo com o slug - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theme, taxonomia

Queria saber se tem como pegar o **name** da taxonomia(wordpress) de acordo com o slug que esta na url(http://localhost/tag/weg/?taxonomy=**comando-e-protecao**).

**Informações da Taxonomia:**

Name: Comando e Proteção 
Slug: comando-e-protecao

Quero que apareça o Name da Taxonomia na tela de acordo com a taxonomia da URL

HTML, PHP, WORDPRESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get_term_by("slug", $_GET['taxonomy'], "tax_aqui");
```